# Cloud Run Continuously deploy: Failed in creating trigger

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, cloud

I have already hit the wall :( Im trying to make continuous deploy of Django app using Dockerfile and cloud run. There is option to do it connecting to cloud build and unfortunately for me it always ends with error below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snabG.png)

Cloud Build trigger creation failed. Continuous Deployment pipeline is not set up. Error while setting necessary roles for Cloud Build Service Account. Required roles: roles/run.admin, roles/iam.serviceAccountUser.

The problem is that my Cloud Build service account has a required roles, image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IYme.png)

Maybe someone had a similar issue and would like to help a friend in need ;)

Thanks in advance!

Dockerfile seems to be ok. Locally is running on docker hub and if I just add it throught container registry and cloud run it runs ok. Location of the file in repository is also ok. I have tried to add those roles to another account like for Cloud Build Service Agent and end up with same error.

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you